# Bandwidth-length product of an optical fiber

Tags: homework-and-exercises, speed-of-light, optical-materials, length

> A multimode step index fiber has a numerical aperture of 0.2 and a core refractive index of 1.47 . Estimate the bandwidth-length product for the fiber assuming only intermodal dispersion when:
>
> (a): there is no mode coupling between guided modes.
>
> (b): mode coupling between guided modes gives a characteristic length equivalent to 0.7 of the actual fiber length"

Using the formula: $BW = 1/\delta Τ \cdot L$

I got 21.5 MHz.Km  for part a.

I got the result by getting $n_2$ from Numerical Aperture  and substituting in the equation.

Question: in part b , which L becomes = 0.7L; the one in the δΤ or the one multiplied by $1/\delta Τ$?

$$\delta Τ = (L\cdot n_1^2\cdot (n_1-n_2))/(c\cdot n_1\cdot n_2)$$

I am not asking to solve my homework, just asking which $L$ in the formula would change in the second part: the numerator or denominator $L$?

Comment: I got the result by getting n2 from N.A and substituting in the equation.

Comment: I am not asking to solve my homework, just asking which L in the formula would change in the second part: the numerator or denominator L?

Comment: Do you expect the answer to get bigger or smaller when there is mode coupling?

Comment: Personally , I expect it to get bigger, though I am not really sure.

Comment: If the signal can travel at different velocities (depending on which mode it's using), I believe the bandwidth will reduce; in other words, you will get the same amount of dispersion with a shorter piece of fiber.

Comment: Can you explain why? I did not understand why it will reduce.

Comment: Dispersion happens when signals travel at different velocities: depending on what path it took the pulse will arrive at a different time. Taken together, the signals traveling all possible paths represent a "blurring" of the input. And the longer the fiber, the greater the time difference between the different paths. A car and a bike take about the same time to get to the end of the drive way; but the car gets to the next city long before the bike.

Comment: "The longer the fiber, the greater the time difference", with L = 0.7L (shorter distance) , doesn't that mean that the time difference decreases which means that the bandwidth increases?